# How to extract specific data from JSON?

Tags: python, json

I can't seem to extract specific data from JSON which I retrieved from a link.
I wrote this code and seems to work fine up to `x` [`print(x)` that is] as you can see from the screenshot-1.

But, it's giving errors while executing the last 2 lines. [Screenshot-2]
I saw this from a video on youtube and tried it on my own.

Maybe I am making a mistake somewhere, Can anybody please tell me where am I doing wrong?

**Code:**

```
import json
import urllib.request

connection = urllib.request.urlopen('http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.json')
js = connection.read()
pj = json.loads(js)
x = json.dumps(pj,indent = 2)
#print(x)

for z in x:
    print(z["count"])
```

[[image: working fine upto print(x)]] [screenshot-1]

[[image: Showing "TypeError: string indices must be integers"]] [Screenshot-2]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What's the expected output?

Comment: I want to extract all the counts

Comment: [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Okay, I will keep this in mind from next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you well know JSON is a standard that allows to pass data from one programming language to another so they could consume them into their objects

an object that can be iterated is pj variable

```
import json
import urllib.request

connection = urllib.request.urlopen('http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.json')
js = connection.read()
pj = json.loads(js)#stores dicts, python objects, iterate them
x = json.dumps(pj,indent = 2)#json here, remember is just a string, cant access them using x['key']


[print(z['count']) for z in pj['comments']]
[97, 97, 90, 90, 88, 87, 87, 80, 79, 79, 78, 76, 76, 72, ...]
```

Comment: Understood, Thank you brother! :D