# How to extract specific value from json data that is now a dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am working on a tool to download a list of open cases from my corporate CRM tool. I have the code to pull them down and into a file. The format of the file is:

```
{
"result": [
      {
         "active":"true",
         "number":"case_123",
         "state":"Open",
         "customer":"",
         "priority":"3 - Moderate",
         "assigned_to":"me",
         "product":"My Product",
         "contact_time_zone":"",
         "opened_at":"23/07/2020 11:10:08",
         "closed_at":""
      },
      "<more cases>"
   ],
}
```

I want to extract all values for the key "number".

I tried to follow some of the suggestions given when you type in the subject of the post. This one seemed close:
[How to extract specific data from JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63855543/how-to-extract-specific-data-from-json)

But did not work.

Here is the code:

```
    import json
    print("Started Reading JSON file")
    with open("sn_data.json", "r", encoding='utf-8') as read_file:
    print("Converting JSON encoded data into Python dictionary")
    developer = json.load(read_file)

    print(developer['result']['number'])
```

This throws:
print(developer['result']['number'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

I have confirmed that I have a dictionary using print(type(developer)).

If I comment out the print above and use:

```
    for number in developer.items():
    print(developer.items["number"])
```

I get:
print(developer.items["number"])
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

I look up the errors and find no real answers. As I am not a full time Python developer, just support guy trying to help out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value for "result" key in your dictionary is a list, so you can't index into it with ['number']. 'number' is a key in a dictionary in that *list*.

result: [{}.{}...]

So you have to iterate over it. Each item in that list is a dict, so you can then iterate into it with ['result']

```
for result in developer['result']:
    print(result['number'])
```

In your second block of code you store a value in a variable called **number**, but then you use a string "number" to access it. That is not the same thing just FYI. Still, dict.items() will return a list and you cant access it like a dict either.

Comment: Thanks! This got me past this. Now to get this into a file. But that is a question for a different time/thread lol

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `developer['result'][0]['number']`. Your variable `Developer` is a dictionary and the key you want, `result` is a list of 1 element (as we can see), so you'll have to first reference the dictionary key (`developer`) then the index (`0` or whatever it is) and then the other dictionary's key `number`